# Automount delays shutdown

Tags: 16.04, samba, shutdown, fstab, automount

Using automount for an SMB NAS. My fstab entry is:

```
//192.168.1.3/Public    /mnt/mybook    cifs   noauto,x-systemd.automount,rw,nofail,users,_netdev,noperm,guest,soft,sec=none  0  0
```

If I do not access /mnt/mybook, shutdown works fine. If I use /mnt/mybook, then shutdown, it takes several minutes to actually shutdown. On my console I see:

```
[ OK ] Stopped Permit User Sessions.    
[ OK ] Stopped target User and Group Name Lookups.   
[ OK ] Stopped target Remote File Systems.  
       Unmounting /mnt/mybook...
```

Then a pause for about 2 minutes, then the following appears:

```
[ 789.041641] CIFS VFS: Server 192.168.1.3 has not responded in 120 seconds. Reconnecting...
```

After another lengthy wait, it finally shuts down.

Here is the info from the "mount" command:

```
//192.168.1.3/Public on /mnt/mybook type cifs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,vers=1.0,sec=none,cache=strict,domain=SEAGATE-3E1F71,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.3,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,noperm,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,_netdev)
```

Acts like the network is shut down before the unmount is attempted, but none of this shows up in the syslog. Any ideas on how to fix this?